# Firebase equalTo() couldn't work correctly

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm developing an Android app with the following Firebase database table:

```
"fav" : {
"-Ktf0tmShJ48-oH76Or3" : {
  "article" : {},
  "articleId" : "1005",
  "id" : 1505034214723,
  "userId" : "xUdklm4VMFa9FJvA15XvlIkYKFA3",
  "userId_articleId" : "xUdklm4VMFa9FJvA15XvlIkYKFA31005"
},
"-Ktf13BfglsB4sFhHv-P" : {
  "article" : {},
  "articleId" : "1001",
  "id" : 1505034257363,
  "userId" : "xUdklm4VMFa9FJvA15XvlIkYKFA3",
  "userId_articleId" : "xUdklm4VMFa9FJvA15XvlIkYKFA31001"
}
}
```

I want to query by the string "userId_articleId" like this:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("fav").orderByChild("userId_articleId").equalTo(firebaseUser.getUid() + article.id)
            .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.exists()){
                for (DataSnapshot data : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    fav = data.getValue(Fav.class);
                    favKey = data.getKey();
                    starItem.setIcon(R.drawable.star);
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.i("fyales","The dataChanged");
        }
    });
}
```

But I can't get the Object I wanted, The weirdest thing is that I can get the Object I want correctly by the key "articleId" or "id". It can also work if if I give the definite value "xUdkl" to "userId_articleId" if the "userId_articleId" in the database is the value "xUdkl" like this:

```
.orderByChild("xUdkl").add....
```

But it can't work if I give the value "xUdklm4VMFa9F" to "userId_articleId" if the "userId_articleId" in the database is "xUdklm4VMFa9F" like this.

```
orderByChild("xUdklm4VMFa9F").add...
```

I don't know why.It is related the length of String or it's just a bug in firebase ? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Ok , thanks .But it is so weird....

Comment: We have no way of knowing what `firebaseUser.getUid() + article.id` are. Can you reproduce the problem with a hard-coded value? If so, please update the question to reflect this.

Comment: Also note that "it can't work" is too vague a description of the problem. I often find it easiest if the code just prints a value. Then tell us what the code printed, and what you expected it to print.

Comment: I set the "xUdkl" to the "userId_articleId" in the database and I can get the object I wanted by .orderByChild("xUdkl").However,I can't get the correct result if I set the "xUdklm4VMFa9F" to the "userId_articleId" in the database by .orderByChild("xUdklm4VMFa9F").

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem...The reason is that I didn't keep the data fresh . So I synced the data before I used them by ref.keepSynced(true).You can get the answer in 
[Enabling Offline Capabilities on Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities).